# Grouping and checking for conditions using a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been asked to compile a SQL query for the following case:

```
ID | PARAMETER  | VALID | VALUE
------------------------------
1  | Event1_Val | 1     | 0
1  | Event2_Val | 0     | 50.00
1  | Event2_Avg | 0     | 55.00
1  | Event1_Avg | 0     | 66.67

2  | Event1_Val | 0     | 37.50
2  | Event2_Val | 1     | 0
2  | Event1_Avg | 0     | 50.00
2  | Event2_Avg | 0     | 66.67
```

where `_Val` is a current value. `_Avg` is the average of the past five values.

**Requirement 1:** If `VALID == 1` (applies only to `_Val` values), do not check that parameter's `_Val` and `_Avg`, but check the other parameter's `_Val` and `_Avg`. In the example above for `ID=1`,  `Event2_Val` and `Event2_Avg` would be checked because `Event1_Val.VALID = 1` (which means `Event1_Val` and `Event1_Avg` would not be checked.)

**Requirement 2:** Check the values of `_Val` and `_Avg` as a result of Requirement 1 for the following conditions:

- `_Val` < 5 **OR**
- `_Val` + 10 < `_Avg`

The conditions above return an alert. In the example above for `ID=2`, `Event1_Val` will return an alert because 37.50 + 10 is less than 50.00.

**Requirement 3:** Indicate the results of Requirement 2

```
ID | PARAMETER  | ALERT
------------------------
1  | Event2_Val | 0 
2  | Event1_Val | 1
```

---

I have tried to check for `VALID` does not equal 1, but that leaves me with the following:

```
ID | PARAMETER  | VALID | VALUE
------------------------------
1  | Event2_Val | 0     | 50.00
1  | Event2_Avg | 0     | 55.00
1  | Event1_Avg | 0     | 66.67

2  | Event1_Val | 0     | 37.50
2  | Event1_Avg | 0     | 50.00
2  | Event2_Avg | 0     | 66.67
```

I do not want to check for the parameter for the event in which `_Val.VALID == 1`. Meaning, for `ID=1`, I do not want to include `Event1_Avg`.

---

**Is there a way to group and check conditions using a query for this case?**  NOTE: There is a strong desire not to change values in the tables.

Comment: So... you group results by 'ID', yes? And within each ID, there'll be two "events", one and only one of which will have a '1' in the 'VALID' column against its _VAL parameter? Is that guaranteed? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes, grouped by `ID`. The 1 in the `VALID` column pertains to the `_VAL` parameter (there are other parameters, but I won't be dealing with those in this query). There will be one event within an ID group in which its `_VAL` will have a `VALID` value of 1, and this is guaranteed for these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.id,
   t1.parameter,
   CASE 
      WHEN (t1.value < 5 OR (t1.value + 10 < t2.value)) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END alert
FROM your_table t1
JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   AND left(t1.parameter, 6) = left(t2.parameter, 6)
   AND t1.parameter LIKE '%_Val'
   AND t2.parameter LIKE '%_Avg'
WHERE 
   t1.valid <> 1
```

Comment: Nice work and thanks for your time. Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8e64/3/0) to confirm it works. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, some comments explaining whats going on:

```
declare @events table
(
ID int
,PARAMETER nvarchar(25)
,VALID bit
,VALUE decimal (18,2)
)

insert into @events(ID, PARAMETER,VALID, VALUE)

select 1  , 'Event1_Val' , 1     , 0
union all
select 1  , 'Event2_Val' , 0     , 50.00
union all
select 1  , 'Event2_Avg' , 0     , 55.00
union all
select 1  , 'Event1_Avg' , 0     , 66.67
union all
select 2  , 'Event1_Val' , 0     , 37.50
union all
select 2  , 'Event2_Val' , 1     , 0
union all
select 2  , 'Event1_Avg' , 0     , 50.00
union all
select 2  , 'Event2_Avg' , 0     , 66.67


select * from @events e

SELECT 
     ID
    ,PARAMETER 
    ,CASE WHEN (VALUE < 5 OR VALUE + 10.00 < AVRG) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ALERT
FROM
(
    select 
        e.ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(e.PARAMETER,4) = '_Val' THEN e.PARAMETER END ) as PARAMETER,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(e.PARAMETER,4) = '_Val' THEN e.VALUE END) as VALUE,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(e.PARAMETER,4) = '_Avg' THEN e.VALUE END) as AVRG
    from @events e
    JOIN
    ( --Get Valid Events
        select ID, REPLACE(REPLACE(PARAMETER,'_Val',''),'_Avg','') as Parameter --returns EventNAme without '_Val' or '_Avg' for grouping porpuses
        from @events
        WHERE RIGHT(PARAMETER,4) = '_Val' and VALID = 0
        GROUP BY ID ,REPLACE(REPLACE(PARAMETER,'_Val',''),'_Avg','')
    ) validEvents --filter by valid events only
        on validEvents.ID = e.ID
        AND validEvents.Parameter = REPLACE(REPLACE(e.PARAMETER,'_Val',''),'_Avg','')
    GROUP BY e.ID
) PIVOTEDRESULTS
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Please see the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656224) for a more concise query that also gets the job done.